# GET data of form submission as a function parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<form action="mycontroller/myfunction" method="GET">

    Age:
    <input type="number" name="age"><br>
    Mobile:
    <input type="text" name="mobile"><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

After the form is submitted, this will go to an url like `mycontroller/myfunction?age=10&mobile=8801266451255`

But I want get the url like `mycontroller/myfunction/10/8801266451255`

where I have a function in mycontroller controller

```
public function myfunction($age='',$mobile='')
{

}
```

Comment: Is this for Laravel or Codeigniter?

Comment: you should capture these params in your route definition, somehting like `/url/{age}/{mobile}

Comment: this is for Codeigniter

Comment: You are trying to use SEGMENTS. What framework are you using ? Or is this plain code written by you...

Comment: Why don't you just use `$this->input->get()` instead of trying to change the url?

Comment: i think its better to pass the data like above and get the data using $_GET in the myfunction

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that this is Codeigniter, consider the following:

```
$this->uri->segment(1); // controller
$this->uri->segment(2); // action
$this->uri->segment(3); // 1stsegment
$this->uri->segment(4); // 2ndsegment
```

In your: "`public function myfunction($age='',$mobile='')`".

Comment: The OP's issue is that he wants the query string to be transformed in to uri segments not that he can't access them :)

Comment: He doesn't even know what segments are. This should "get him on the right track". Nobody is going to write everything for him.

Comment: I know about segment.but I want my url will be like "mycontroller/myfunction/10/8801266451255"

Comment: You cannot actually do that, unless you change your method from GET to POST and the action  to action="mycontroller/myfunction/$age/$mobile" for example.

Comment: Event better, get rid of the form, and just create hyperlink like href="mycontroller/myfunction/$age/$mobile" and then the URL will become mycontroller/myfunction/10/8801266451255. There is many ways around...

Comment: Yes, there are many ways around it... the more you test the more you learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Pass input via post method

View:

```
<!-- Use CI form helper-->  
<?php echo form_open('controller_name/function', array('class'=>'form-horizontal')); ?>

   <label for="age" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age:</label>
   <input type="number" name="age"><br>
Mobile:
   <label for="mobile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age:</label>
   <input type="text" name="mobile"><br>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
my_function(){

 if($this->input->post('submit'){

    $age = $this->input->post('age');
    $mobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use js or jquery

There are batter ways to solve this problem, but i hope this will help in this context. try this.

```
<form id="fm">

    Age:
    <input type="number" name="age" id="name"><br>
    Mobile:
    <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mob"><br>

    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Save" id="save">
</form>
<script>

$("#save").click(function(){
    var age= $("#name").val();
    var mobile= $("#mob").val();

    var data=age+"/"+mobile;
    alert(data);

    window.location='mycontroller/myfunction/'+data;

})

</script>
```

don't forget to include jquery

Answer (score 0):

**Submit Form with GET/POST method in another function then redirect to `myfunction` with parameter**

```
<form action="mycontroller/mynewfunction" method="POST">

Age:
<input type="number" name="age"><br>
Mobile:
<input type="text" name="mobile"><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
```

then in controller

```
public function mynewfunction()
{
    $age=$this->input->post('age');
    $mobile=$this->input->post('mobile');

    redirect("mycontroller/myfunction/$age/$mobile");
}
```

***This process will help to validate form also***